# Why is processing my CSV file taking forever to complete?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a 90GB CSV file, from which I need to extract some columns and then change the strings into integers and store it in a new CSV. I wrote the code and tested it on a small sample CSV file of about 100,000 rows. It worked fine, so I proceeded to feed the original CSV into the program. I knew it would take overnight to complete, and I in the morning I found the program was not finished, and the processed file was only about 1GB in size, which was really small as I expected it to be at least 10 GB by the time it completed, allowing for the fact that integers take less space then strings, and also that I was extracting only 10 out of 50+ columns from the original CSV.

I modified the code to do the extraction and processing separately. I found that, without the processing, the extraction completes in 10-11 hours resulting in a CSV that is 38GB in size. Then I did the processing of the extracted CSV, which still had not finished after 18 hours of running, with the resulting CSV file only about 1.5GB in size.

My code for processing is this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'csv'
require 'time'

CSV.open('FormattedColumns.csv', "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["_time", "article_category_id", "articleID", "date_wday", "datetime", "lat", "lon", "platform", "push", "udid"]
  CSV.foreach('ExtractedColumns.csv', :headers=>true) do |row|

    time=Time.parse(row[0]).to_i

    article_category_id=row[1].to_i

    articleID=row[2].to_i

    if row[3]=='sunday'
      weekday=7
    elsif row[3]=='saturday'
      weekday=6
    elsif row[3]=='friday'
      weekday=5
    elsif row[3]=='thursday'
      weekday=4
    elsif row[3]=='wednesday'
      weekday=3
    elsif row[3]=='tuesday'
      weekday=2
    elsif row[3]=='monday'
      weekday=1
    end     

    datetime = row[4].to_i

    lat = row[5].to_f

    lon = row[6].to_f

    if row[7]=='Android'
      platform=2
    elsif row[7]=='iPhone'
      platform=1
    end 

    if row[8]=='Y'
      push=1
    elsif row[8]=='N'
      push=0
    end

    unless udids.include?(row[9])
      udids << row[9]
    end
    udid = udids.index(row[9]) + 1

    array = [time, article_category_id, articleID, weekday, datetime, lat, lon, platform, push, udid]
    csv<<array
  end
end
```

What could be the reason for this?

As far as I can see, it's a simple program, and, with the smaller sample program of 100,000 rows, when I tried the extraction and processing separately, they both finished in about 1-2 minutes.

Comment: Are you running out of RAM, trying to keep all that data in memory at once?

Comment: No, my computer is not slowing down. So, I guess RAM is okay.

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't guess, I'd use tools to actually check on how much RAM the ruby process is taking, and if your workstation is swapping.

Comment: Found the problem! There was one column in my CSV where the program had to check all previous values if it exists before, and if not then assign a new value to it. That was what was taking the time. It sounds simple now, but figuring it out was not obvious :D

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the `smarter_csv` gem, which can process chunks of the CSV data (multiple rows) and hand them to an asynchronous worker, e.g. a Sidekiq worker.

For writing the output, it might be faster for each worker to assemble output snippets for each batch into separate files and concatenate them later.